# Cannot resolve method 'setSslContextParameters' in 'NettyComponent'

Tags: https, apache-camel, ssl-certificate, netty

I'm trying to adding ssl support to the programe In camel.But I'm getting error as "Cannot resolve method 'setSslContextParameters' in 'NettyComponent'" .

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-netty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

these are my camel and netty version. Have any idea about resolving this issue. camel version is 3.21.0.

```
            KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
            ksp.setResource("/users/home/server/keystore.jks");
            ksp.setPassword("keystorePassword");

            KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
            kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
            kmp.setKeyPassword("keyPassword");

            SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
            scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

            NettyComponent nettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("netty", NettyComponent.class);
            nettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
```

[image: ScreenShot in the intellij]

Comment: The code seems to be incorrect/outdated, it should rather be `nettyComponent.getConfiguration().setSslContextParameters(scp);`

Comment: The corresponding PR https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/11283